# Download Manager for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, download-manager, download

IS there a download manager for Mac OS X that allows me to interrupt and resume large downloads? (I'm trying to download the Apple Developer Tools update, but a 3+ GB file size seldom plays nicely with my internet connection.

**EDIT:**

I prefer a free solution if possible.

**EDIT2:**

I need it to be able to download from the Apple Developer site, which requires authentication. The downloads there are huge - my bandwidth isn't. Using Folx and authentication, I successfully downloaded ... drumroll please ... an intermediate HTML file.

Comment: Safari usually is able to do this on its own, I think.

Comment: Start a download in Safari to get you authenticated, then resume the one that was interrupted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I highly recommended using [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/iGetter.html) it was much better than other one.

- [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/iGetter.html)

But also you can use:

- [Download Accelerator Plus (DAP)](http://www.speedbit.com/mac/)
- [Folx (free)](http://mac.eltima.com/download-manager.html) but can pay money and upgrade it to pro
- [Speed Download](http://www.yazsoft.com/products/speed-download/) (paid one) : nice one with a lot of features.
- [Leech](http://manytricks.com/leech/) (paid one) : clean UI.
- [Folx](http://mac.eltima.com/download-manager.html) (free one) : download & torrents manager.

Besides, if you use Terminal and can install packages, I recommend [AXEL](http://wilmer.gaast.net/downloads/axel-1.0b.tar.gz). I myself use this one. After installation is complete you can use the command below to do what you want.

```
axel -n 100 -s 5242880 "your download link"
```

The -n 100 show the number of your connection to the server and the -s 5242880 use for limiting the speed,-s 5242880 in above example will try to keep the average speed around 5242880 (5120 Kilobyte per/sec).

Comment: +1 for axel. I typically only use -n 10 (or raise it enough to saturate the pipe).

Comment: Speed Download is good.. but the software do not support OSX Mountain Lion

Comment: **axel**! especially you can install it from [homebrew](http://brew.sh). `brew install axel` and you're gold.

Answer (score 2):

[Leech](http://manytricks.com/leech/) and [Speed Download](http://www.yazsoft.com/products/speed-download/) are well known, the former has 25 program launches without restriction as trial. Should be plenty for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Safari, OmniWeb, and iCab all have resumable downloads available in the Downloads window. Safari and OmniWeb are free, iCab is shareware.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out iGetter once. Its not a freeware but it is good download manager. 
http://www.igetter.net