# Download manager for windows that can import list from text file

Tags: windows, download, download-manager

I was using a downloader manager, but recently discovered it contains some potentially dangerous modules.

One of the features available was the ability to import a list of files from a text file to download multiple files simultaneously, but now I need to remove that download manager.

Are there some other download managers, or other ways, I can achieve this?

Comment: What about [wget](http://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget)?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini: AFAIK wget is not a real download manager - for example it is not able to efficiently manage parallel downloads from a single queue of URLs and without external help it does not do parallel downloads at all. ...or am I wrong?

Comment: @pabouk: It's true, wget doesn't support parallel download, but can be invoked multiple times in a command (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430810/wget-download-with-multiple-connection-simultaneously) for example) and it is (at the moment) not dangerous. Surely there are more advanced solutions, like [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) or similar, but I've not yet tried them.

Comment: For the question itself, wouldn't it be an alternative to rewrite it to be a generic solution for a text-file in general: say, how one could do this on Windows, rather than wanting a product specifically? (Disclaimer: my answer approaches it this way.)

Comment: @Thor How do they classify here if a question seeks product recomendations or not. What about these... [Download manager for OSX](http://superuser.com/questions/215890/download-manager-for-mac-os-x?rq=1), [Windows equivalent of wget](http://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget?lq=1)

Comment: @swapna It depends, but to go on your examples: number one is closed as constructive, and in my subjective opinion I would remark that the second one is looking for the exact same, but for a different plattform. Other answers here could also be ways to emulate the same application on the different platform.

Comment: This is the first Google result, and it's closed.  Good job everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using a more permanent solution to the issue, by say, using PowerShell to get a list of download items and then send this to whatever download manager you want to use.

1. Start Windows Powershell with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then enter `powershell`.
2. Run the following snippet with appropriate adjustments.

   ```
   Get-Content C:\path\to\file.txt | ForEach-Object { Start-Process "C:\path\to\download-manager.exe" -ArgumentList $_ }
   ```

*The above line assumes that you have a text-file where every download is on its own line.*